# RPC procedure call failed when running C# windows application

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word, comexception

I have requirement to create bunch of word document(approx 9000) from some word document template. While creating document I am dynamically populating one grid in the template and then saving the word document.
I have to complete all my requirement and able to generate the word document. However when I run my windows application, after creating 1000 document it fails with exception

> Remote procedure call failed to start.

Sometime it fails after creating 2000 document with same error. Could anyone please help me to fix this issue. Let me know if you need any further details on this. Here is my code.

```
Word.Document doc = docs.Open(ref oFilePath, ref oMissing...); 
Word.Table tbl = doc.Tables[1]; 
if (tbl == null) return; 
using (SqlDataReader oReader1 = command.ExecuteReader()) { 
  while (oReader1.Read()){
         i = i + 1;
         tbl.Rows.Add(ref oMissing); 
     //doc.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add; 
   if (oReader1[0].ToString().Equals(oReader1[2].ToString())) { 
     tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = oReader1[0].ToString(); 
    } else { 
         tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = oReader1[2].ToString(); 
        tbl.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = oReader1[3].ToString(); 
   } }
```

Comment: Can you please post line of code where it breaks and few lines before

Comment: Use Task Manager, Processes tab.  If you see many copies of winword.exe running then you are doing it wrong.  We can't see you doing it wrong.

Comment: @Yuri Here is the Code. here i am reading template document and dynamically populating table grid inside the document. And then saving that document. Issue happens anytime in the else section of the code.

Comment: Word.Document doc = docs.Open(ref oFilePath, ref oMissing...);
Word.Table tbl = doc.Tables[1];
if (tbl == null) return;
using (SqlDataReader oReader1 = command.ExecuteReader())
{
while (oReader1.Read()){
i = i + 1;
tbl.Rows.Add(ref oMissing);
//doc.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add;
if (oReader1[0].ToString().Equals(oReader1[2].ToString()))
{
    tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = oReader1[0].ToString();
}
else
{
    tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = oReader1[2].ToString();
 tbl.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = oReader1[3].ToString();
}
}

Comment: @HansPassant I have checked task manager and i am not getting winword.exe for more than once. SOi am good there.

Answer (score 0):

After you done with inserting data into your word document make sure that the document is properly released.

```
    wdApp = null;
    GC.Collect(); 
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); 
    GC.Collect(); 
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

after each document.